# How to detect any duplicate in each row and column in 2d array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I was given an assignment to check for duplicates. If there are duplicates then we have to return false else true. As I am new to python I am unable to write the code. So it will be helpful if you guys help me with it.
For Example

```
    test = ([1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,4],
    [1,2,3,4])
```

should return false.

Comment: what do you consider a duplicate ?   each row with the other rows or the elements inside the rows ?  for example does `[1,2,3,4]` have no duplicates or is it duplicated with the other `[1,2,3,4]` ?

Comment: numbers in the rows...For example if number 3 is present four time in a row then it is considered as duplicate and the function should return false in this case

Comment: so `[1,2,3,3]` would be considered a duplicate because it has two `3`'s.... ?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: but it will be row wise....but if we consider it as a column then there are no duplicates. hope you its clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through each element and perform two checks - the row and a column - if duplicate occurs return false. Hence the array is two-dimensional you will have to perform a nested loop:

```
    for row in array:
        for cell in row:
            if check(array[row][cell]):
                return false
    return true
```

The check() function have to test, if any other cell in the same column or row is the same. So simmilar iteration is to do. Remember not to check the cell with its own value. Details of implementation are great excercise, try to do it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic recipe.

- iterate through the rows `i`.
- then iterate through the items in the rows `j`.
- blank list to house items `x` and check for duplicates.

This would work:

```py
test = ([1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,4],
    [1,2,3,4])

def test_array(test):
    for i in test:
        x = []
        for j in i:
            if j in x:
                return False
            else:
                x.append(j)
    return True

test_array(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

`no_duplicates` below will do this. There's a helper that checks lists for duplicates. The helper is slow because set creation is slow, but for many uses this will be effective. Modifying the helper is probably the easiest way to speed this up, if necessary.

```
def list_no_duplicates(my_list):
    return len(my_list) == len(set(my_list))

def no_duplicates(arr):
    return all(list_no_duplicates(e) for e in arr)
```